# where to find exoplayer old documentation

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using Exoplayer 2.10.5 And I found it very difficult to work with as they not only release new version of exoplayer but deleted the old documentation completely. So, I need old documentation of exoplayer Otherwise it would be so difficult to edit the existing project as the project is so complicated like stackoverflow.

how to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wayback machine for watch old docs https://web.archive.org/